# How to use SQL and PHP to populate new pages in a site?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a project, in which it is required for me to build a number of images which will be linked to pages containing information, which will be obtained from a database.  Can someone suggest some tutorials to help me achieve this as I don't know what to search for?

My end goal is something similar to http://www.booking.com/city/bg/sofia.en-gb.html?sid=952e191dc66b2059dfc22f7c4d2f33ef;dcid=1;city=-838489;ilp=1 where I can click the hotel name or image and go to a page which gives information about the particular hotel selected.

**Clarification of the question**

My project involves 2 sets of pages, the main pages and a number of link pages.  A super simple example of a main page:

```
<body>
  <h1>Home</h1>
    <a href='info.php[kidsparties]'>Kid's Parties</a>
    <a href= 'info.php[teenparties]'>Teen Parties</a>
    ...
   <a href='info.php[schoolparties]'>School Parties</a>
<body>
```

When the links are clicked they will lead to a page of the same structure but with different information. For example if the first link is selected:

```
<body>
  <h1>Kid's Parties</h1>
   <p>Some text here</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Do the easy bits first.

Comment: @N00b 101 I am buiding a Content Management system for a school project, which apart from the main pages, will contain links which will lead to pages with the same structure but different information.  Similar to the site I have posted as a general idea.  I know how to generate the data if it is in the same page, however I have no idea how to make the data generate in a new page.

Comment: [The manual is your friend](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/index.php)

Comment: @Jensen -> easy bits are done.  :) this is what I have left from the project. And I have no idea which are the easy bits since I have no idea what I need to do.

Comment: Break the problem down into pieces. You'll need a database to store image paths and other metadata, a folder to store the images themselves, and a PHP page containing a loop to read rows from the database using a SQL query, and render image tags.

Comment: (In general it is not worth searching for a tutorial for the exact thing you want to do - work through a variety of tutorials until the basic concepts make more sense to you. This will give you the transferrable skills to pick up any new project).

Comment: You have to give information seperately to every link that lets the page know what information to get from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following tables:

```
Images (id, src, datetime);
Content (id, content, user_id, created, updated); 
content_img (id, content_id, image_id);
```

If you are making a CMS for the school, be prepared to be required to make Page Roles, this is levels of user permission etc. Administrator, Moderator, Student etc.

Acitivity_log,

```
id, 
user_id, 
action, 
object_id,
description,
datetime,
```

This can look like this:

```
id: 4b340550242239
user_id: 1546058
action: "Edit"
object_id: 887987779879
description: 'User1 edited article "An Introduction to Psychology 101" '
datetime: 2015-07-21 14:30:59
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I have already created the database, which is similar to that.  There is no need for me to create a user_id  since only one or 2 people will be editing the site.   My table contains -> id, title, image.

Comment: @Chri, still it is very necessary, to keep track of User Activity.

Comment: Would it make sense to keep track of user activity when the user logs in  to edit the page and logs out  rather than as part of the content table?   ie -> Login: UserID, LoginTime, LogoutTime

Comment: @Chri, yes, it would make sense, since an Administrator can confirm a lot via an activity log. Imagine if the CMS will have more than two Users, remember, nobody is around forever, and every person is replaced by another - everywhere.

Comment: Thanks alot ta.  Will update the activity table and get back to the questions.

Comment: Sweet. BTW, wordpress is open-source, and it is written in PHP, if you are interested check out their code, and see how it works. BTW, some of it is inline PHP which is BAD BAD to use. I'd recommend PHP Template Processor, PHP PDO, a custom session manager which utilizes PHP's session functions except, that it stores the session in the database in a session table.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm trying to build, something similar to wordpress but customized to my needs.  From where can I get the code to wordpress?

Comment: You can modify wordpress.

Comment: Well, I am almost running out of time. If you feel satisfied with the information I have provided so far, please go ahead and mark this post as the answer.

Comment: Here is the WordPress code in PHP: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress

Comment: @Chri, was this INFORMATION useful enough to get you going?

Comment: Hopefully it is :) Will ask questions if I get stuck.

Comment: @Chri, I will be around and capture your next questions. Thx.

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanting to have PHP serve content for pages that don't exist as separate files you heed to trap the 404 error from the server and interpret the URL (in $SERVER[] somewhere) to produce the substitute page,  (in apache this is activated via the "ERRORDOC 404" directive IIRC)

Be sure to emit a "HTTP/200" header so that crawlers understand that it's a real page.

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more clearly since I'm a bit of newb in php. Thanks. :)

Comment: What @Jansen, meant is, that you must implement a 404 handler, that reads the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; most websites still operate according to this behavior, well embedded and implemented into sites since 1998.

Comment: However, @Jansen's proposal, is less of an issue now, as you can easily solve this. Moreover, the robots.txt can be used to allow Web Spiders crawl your site content.